# Need python library to update huge Excel file with pivot table

Tags: python, excel

I have tried using Openpyxl to update the Excel file which have pivot table, I am getting memory error. I used Optimized reader (link - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html) and set read_only to false, still getting memory error

Answer (score 0):

From my experience between `pandas` and `openpyxl`, i think you will be totally satisfied with `pandas`.

### Pandas

---

[***According to `pandas` documentation***](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

> ***pandas** is a fast, powerful, flexible and easy to use open source data analysis and manipulation tool,
> built on top of the Python programming language.*

Now, you'll ask, **How is this will help me to operate my data with `excel`?**

Simply, check;

[Reading and Writing Excel (`.xlsx`) Files in Python with the Pandas Library](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-excel-files-in-python-with-the-pandas-library/)

### NumPy

---

[***According to `NumPy` documentation***](https://numpy.org/)

**POWERFUL N-DIMENSIONAL ARRAYS**

> *Fast and versatile, the NumPy vectorization, indexing, and broadcasting concepts are the de-facto standards of array computing today.*

**NUMERICAL COMPUTING TOOLS**

> *NumPy offers comprehensive mathematical functions, random number generators, linear algebra routines, Fourier transforms, and more.*

This reference will help you to understand how can we play with data using **NumPy**.

[Python **NumPy** step-by-step](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-numpy/)

Comment: I want to update an existing excel sheet, i see only read and write with pandas